# I need help sorting a list within a list for a json dictionary

Tags: python, json, list, sorting, dictionary

```
    {
      "version": 51,
      "players": [
        {
      "ratings": [
        {
          "hgt": 43,
          "stre": 11,
          "spd": 49,
          "endu": 78,
          "pss": 54,
          "wst": 44,
          "sst": 32,
          "stk": 36,
          "oiq": 45,
          "chk": 16,
          "blk": 24,
          "fcf": 50,
          "diq": 32,
          "glk": 11,
          "fuzz": 1.5322881555300292,
          "ovr": 47,
          "pos": "C",
          "pot": 47,
          "season": 2022,
          "skills": [],
          "ovrs": {
            "C": 47,
            "W": 41,
            "D": 28,
            "G": 1
          },
          "pots": {
            "C": 47,
            "W": 41,
            "D": 28,
            "G": 1
          }
        }
      ],
     ]
    }
```

> This may not be a perfect json file as I have just put the main parts I need I want to sort my OVR of several players (not just this one)
> And I’m having trouble sorting the lists in order to do this.

```
for player in data["players"]:
  ratings = player["ratings"]
  sorted_players = sorted(data["players"], key=lambda x: x[“ratings]["ovr"])
```

> This was my attempt but I just get a type error any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the complete error stack ?

Comment: Please reduce the dictionary to the minimum needed to clarify your problem than also show your expected output. It's unclear exactly what you're trying to sort

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the value for `"ratings"` is a list so you need to access the first element of it before trying to retrive the value for `"ovr"`:

```
players_sorted_by_ovr_rating_descendingly = \
    sorted(data["players"], key=lambda p: p["ratings"][0]["ovr"], reverse=True)
for player in players_sorted_by_ovr_rating_descendingly:
    print(player)
```

Here is an indented version of your example that highlights this:

```
data = {
    "version": 51,
    "players": [
        {
            "ratings": [
                {
                    "hgt": 43,
                    "stre": 11,
                    "spd": 49,
                    "endu": 78,
                    "pss": 54,
                    "wst": 44,
                    "sst": 32,
                    "stk": 36,
                    "oiq": 45,
                    "chk": 16,
                    "blk": 24,
                    "fcf": 50,
                    "diq": 32,
                    "glk": 11,
                    "fuzz": 1.5322881555300292,
                    "ovr": 47,
                    "pos": "C",
                    "pot": 47,
                    "season": 2022,
                    "skills": [],
                    "ovrs": {
                        "C": 47,
                        "W": 41,
                        "D": 28,
                        "G": 1
                    },
                    "pots": {
                        "C": 47,
                        "W": 41,
                        "D": 28,
                        "G": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```